# Vue Js how to use in mixins in single file template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs2, vue-component

Hi everyone im new to Vue JS and im trying to use mixins on my filters using single file template and I'm having some hard time

Error I'm getting

```
Unknown custom element: <side-bar-one> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

component.js

```
Vue.component('sideBarOne', require('./component/sidebars/sideBarOne.vue'));
```

sideBarOne.vue

```
import { default as config } from '../../../config';
import { filters as filter } from '../../../mixins/filters';

export default {
        mixins: [
            filter,
        ],
        mounted: function() {
        }
 }
```

filters.js

```
import { default as config } from '../config';
module.exports = {
    filters: {
        useLGLogo( str ) {
            if( str ) {
                return config.LG_LOGO + str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toUpperCase() + '.png';
            }
        },
        useMDLogo( str ) {
            if( str ) {
                return config.MD_LOGO + str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toUpperCase() + '.png';
            }
        },
        useSMLogo( str ) {
            if( str ) {
                return config.SM_LOGO + str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toUpperCase() + '.png';
            }
        },
    }
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've made some changes on my files and made it working

filters.js

```
    import { default as config } from '../config';
    var filters = {
        filters: {
            useLGLogo( str ) {
                if( str ) {
                    return config.LG_LOGO + str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toUpperCase() + '.png';
                }
            },
            useMDLogo( str ) {
                if( str ) {
                    return config.MD_LOGO + str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toUpperCase() + '.png';
                }
            },
            useSMLogo( str ) {
                if( str ) {
                    return config.SM_LOGO + str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toUpperCase() + '.png';
                }
            },
        }
    };

export default filters;
```

sideBarOne.vue

```
import { default as filters } from '../../../mixins/filters';
    export default {
        mixins: [
            filters,
        ],
        mounted: function() {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can import default exports with a single name. `import filters from`, instead of `import { default as filters }`